# Object parameter/function and/or ternary operator confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working through R Murphy's [JQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html) and am stuck on a snippet of code in her solution: [slideshow.js](https://github.com/rmurphey/jqfundamentals/blob/master/solutions/slideshow.js).

She's created the following function (I've removed some of the navigation code in order to focus on the core functionality of fading images in and out):

```
fadeCallback = function() {
            if (manualMode) { return; }

            var $this = $(this),
                $next = getItem($this, 'next'),
                num = $this.prevAll().length + 1;

            // set the timeout for showing
            // the next item in 5 seconds
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                showItem($this, $next);
            }, 5000);
        };
```

Inside fadeCallback she calls getItem() to get the next sibling of $this:

```
getItem = function($item, trav) {
            var $returnItem = $item[trav]();
            return $returnItem.length ? 
                $returnItem : 
                $items[(trav == 'next') ? 'first' : 'last']();
        },
```

It seems to me that inside getItem(), in the line...

```
$items[(trav == 'next') ? 'first' : 'last']();
```

...trav is never **not** going to be 'next'. i.e. Nowhere else in the code do we set 'trav' to anything but 'next'. Yet by virtue of the code testing whether trav equals 'next' it implies that there are cases where trav != 'next'. But I can't identify any such case.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Don't use a ternary operator unless you really, really, really need to (which is probably never). It should only be for really, really simple if trees.

Comment: @JaredFarrish ternary operators are not that bad. Nested ternary operators are the _devil_.

Comment: @Raynos - Ternaries are opportunistic, yet by nature are very different from descriptive if structures. Why shorten what is relatively simple to visually bug check?

Comment: @maerics - Because I've been there, I guess. I still use ternaries, but rarely. It's easier/more comfortable for me to use a simple if structure.

Comment: @JaredFarrish It depends whether you use one line if statements. I never do so, so I can see why you want a one line ternary. Although almost all usecases of ternarys in simple assignments can be done with `||` or `&&`.

Comment: @Raynos - I understand; my whole point is, if code is for humans, make it human-expressive (hence, no ternaries where not needed).

Comment: @Raynos - Also, I never use one-line if statements. Never. I consider a good time to fact-check my coding of my practices, if I construct an entire single if structure to accomplish something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prevBtn = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'button',
    value: 'previous'
}).appendTo($controls),

$nextBtn = $('<input/>', {
    type: 'button',
    value: 'next'
}).appendTo($controls),

$prevBtn.bind('click', { direction : 'prev' }, handleBtnClick);
$nextBtn.bind('click', { direction : 'next' }, handleBtnClick);

handleBtnClick = function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    manualMode = true;

    var $currentItem = $items.filter(':visible'),
        $itemToShow = getItem($currentItem, e.data.direction);

    showItem($currentItem, $itemToShow);
};
```

It's clearly being used for `prev`.

Comment: Ugh. I'd commented this code out to focus just on the fading. It never occurred to me to check this. Sorry for the wasted bandwidth.